# How To Generate Multiline Download File Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, download, webclient

I'm creating a Minecraft .mcfunction file for a datapack that the user can generate based on inputed info of what the .mcfunction does. I have everything else done, but can't seem to make a downloadable file. I did some research and found this code shown below, problem is the file keeps printing everything on one line, also I'm not sure how to change it from .txt to .mcfunction

```
<script text="text/javascript">

function Download(name, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', name);

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        pom.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else {
        pom.click();
    }
}

</script>
```

Does anyone know how to make this show as multi-line text, and not print on one line? I know the string variable I'm inputting is correct because I can see what it looks like after getting sent to console when pressing f12. it shows on multiple lines on console accurately, but won't show up as multiple lines when I download the file. any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: 
I also saw something about adding this line of code, but not sure where I'm supposed to put it, or how to use it in this function.

```
downloadURI("data:text/html," + parsed.join("\r\n"), "name.txt");
```

Edit: 
just found out opening the file in notepad++ displays correctly ._.

Comment: What are you opening the file with when it appears with no line breaks?

Comment: Also, I think more details are needed - what calls the Download function? What is the format of the data passed into it (i.e. where do `name` and `text` come from)?

Comment: oh wait, didn't think of that, double clicking a txt gave no line breaks, I just used notepad++ and it displayed correctly ._. although any ideas on how to change the file type to .mcfunction?

Comment: name and text are strings getting passed in, to show what those do, I would have to paste in a thousand lines of code, those have already been tested in console and appear to work properly

Comment: You need to replace your `\n`s with `\r\n`s - having said that, Notepad should be displaying it as expected - https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/05/08/windows_notepad_unix_linux_macos/ - As for changing the filename, try name = `name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mcfunction";`

Comment: To write a better question, you should give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - so in your case, show a call to the `Download` function with example strings for `name` and `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
<script text="text/javascript">


function ninjaShopDownload(name, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain+ parsed.join("\r\n");charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', name+".mcfunction");

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        pom.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else {
        pom.click();
    }
}

</script>
```

I will leave this up in-case anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `\n`s with `\r\n`s for them to display as you wish in Windows Notepad. As for changing the filename, try `name = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mcfunction";`